# preg_match_all to match strings within anchor links, excluding "<" and ">" characters

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I need preg_match_all to match something like following:

```
<a href="cart.php?Stock=11.482&qty=1">Buy</a>
```

The code I'm using:

```
preg_match_all("'Stock=[^><]&qty=1\">Buy</a>'si", $source, $matches);
```

I need it to match everything before the `&qty=1">Buy</a>` and after the `<a href="cart.php?Stock=`, *except the `<` or `>` characters*.  However, the following code does not work.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building further on your regex you just had to add a * after the character class

```
Stock=[^><]*&qty=1\">Buy</a>
```

If you want to match the number 11.482 add parenthesis so that group 1 contains this number

```
Stock=([^><]*)&qty=1\">Buy</a>
```